# What does the print on Franky's shirt mean?

Tags: one-piece

> [image]
>   Cropped from Chapter 804, page 16

The print on Franky's shirt reads something like "**I☀HT**". I Googled about it and nothing came up. Also, I have checked the One Piece Wikia page and it doesn't have any details about the logo. What does it mean and does it have any significance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's supposed to be a sun.  Like those shirts that say "I <3 NY".  So "I (sun) {something}" - "HoT", maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I found this IoHT is acronym for Institute of Human Thermodynamics, [see here.](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/IoHT) Or maybe not, I don't know :D

Comment: This could potentially be a sneak reference to Jack Sun, The general manager of HT-Tools

Comment: @JTR: lol, highly unlikely, unless Oda is a fan of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 11):

Some comments on [a chapter review in Japanese](https://web.archive.org/web/20170804185837/https://onepiece-log.com/blog-entry-230.html) suggest that the sun is a reference to the rising sun, so "AM", as in "in the morning"/"Ante Meridian". It then becomes "I AM HT". HT would be the acronym of 変態 (HenTai) or pervert.

So that would mean the T-shirt is actually subtly saying **"I am a pervert"**.

Comment: Knowing Franky it wouldn't surprise me if he wore a t-shirt to convey that message. Please note that HenTai can also be interpreted as a 'shapeshifter' which he is, being a cyborg and all..

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant abbreviation of "HT" I found was "Hull Maintenance Technician", which is a US Navy occupational rating.

Though now that I think about it, the "I AM HenTai" makes more sense for Franky after all.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another theory that became pretty common online in the light of recent events in the manga that should be mentioned for sake of completion.

spoilers ahead: do not read if you haven't seen the full Wano arc

> [image]
>  Some argue that the image is an hint to the real name of the Gum Gum fruit and its nature. If you read the letters in an N pattern you get Hito. N would be the initials of Nika, and the sun a reference to his title as the "Sun God".

Obviously I don't know how realistic this is.
On one side many fans see Oda as someone who loves to foreshadows mayor plots elements VERY ahead of time: Shanks uses *haki* in the first issue of the manga, Eneru probably used a form of haki too (and his "kami" form was probably an awakened fruit)...
Yet other fans also claim that most of these are postumous-retcons crafted to give bigger significance to older plot elements. And other groups even go as far to claim that Oda is quite toxic and would go as far as rewrite his own plot and trashing entire characters if someone "dared" to make a correct theory on future plot elements (usually Carrot/Yamato and the Zodiac crew members theory is mentioned in such claims).

To put it shortly: **I am not sure at all that the claims in the spoiler can be considered true at all**. Probably it is an intricate case of [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) - an attempt to give some reasoning to something that probably was just a random joke.

Answer (score -1):

It’s a symbolization of the Haki that’s going to be coming out in the new chapters. I’m pretty sure it’s gonna be a new type most likely starting with the letter T.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While we appreciate anyone's contribution, note that pure opinion/speculative answer is discouraged. Instead, consider [edit]ing and trying to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.